# increasing java heap size pace

Tags: java, linux

I need to increase Java heap size to 2GB RAM. For doing the same I used the command as a user (I did not do this as root user):

```
$ export JVM_ARGS="-Xmx2048m"
```

However, the java heap size does not increase after doing it.

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
    uintx AdaptivePermSizeWeight                    = 20              {product}           
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0               {pd product}        
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0               {product}           
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520        {product}           
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 1054841216      {product}           
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728       {product}           
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 16877879296     {product}           
    uintx MaxPermSize                               = 174063616       {pd product}        
    uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}        
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024            {pd product}        
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024            {pd product}        
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.4.0.el6_6-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

Can someone suggest as to where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the environment variable is [`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html):

```
$ export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Xmx2G'
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'MaxHeapSize'
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx2G
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2147483648                          {product}
openjdk version "1.8.0_40-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-internal-b27)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Also how can I set mmap file space to unlimited for my java application

Comment: I don't think the JVM has an option for that (although I'm not really sure; don't quote me on it). The OS may impose limits for user sessions; check `ulimit -v`. If that is not unlimited, most likely the limit is configured in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Remove it there, start a new user session (log out and in again), then it should be unlimited. Mind you, some of this is guesswork.

Comment: I have already set "*   soft  core   unlimited" in /etc/security/limits.conf. Should I also set hard core to unlimited? Also thanks for all the wonderful help till now

Comment: `core` is the limit for the size of core dumps. The one you want to set to unlimited is `as`, both hard and soft. The hard limit is the limit beyond which the soft limit cannot be increased. Your system probably a man page for this; try `man limits.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

1. 2048 in -Xmx2048m means 2048 MB (2GB) so for 4GB you will have to use -Xmx4096m
2. Now you are not providing the argument to java, to do so, you will have to run it as follows:

`java -Xmx4096m`

For your example:

```
java -Xmx4096m -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

Comment: I am using Jena framework. I can use just its binaries. So, I can not set java heap size to 2 GB using java -Xmx2048.